# how to print the output of multiple function calls in the same line?

Tags: r

```
condition<-function(temp){

V<-c()

for (i in length(temp)){


if(temp[i]>100){


V[i]<-"Hot"

    }
    else{
        V[i]<-"Normal"
        
    }

}
a<-V[!is.na(V)]


return(a)
}

print(condition(c(101,93,777,110)))


print(condition(c(90,120)))


print(condition(c(97,55,51)))
```

The Current output is

```
[1] "Hot"


[1] "Hot"


[1] "Normal"
```

But I want

```
[1] "Hot" "Hot" "Normal"
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your function as written is only using the last element of each vector, rather than returning a value for every element, which is what I assume you want. Instead, use `ifelse()`, which is vectorized:

```
condition <- function(temp) {
  V <- ifelse(temp > 100, "Hot", "Normal")
  V[!is.na(V)]
}

condition(c(101,93,777,110))
# [1] "Hot"    "Normal" "Hot"    "Hot"
```

If you want a single vector from multiple calls to `condition()`, combine the results using `c()`:

```
c(
  condition(c(101,93,777,110)),
  condition(c(90,120)),
  condition(c(97,55,51))
)
# [1] "Hot"    "Normal" "Hot"    "Hot"    "Normal" "Hot"    "Normal" "Normal"
# [9] "Normal"
```

Comment: But my code has three print statements and i want out put of all the three print statements in single line. That's the real problem i am facing .

Comment: @RockySinghania see my edited answer.